# Pandas Dataframe initialize and complete each group with 0.0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, which looks like the following:

```
df =
A             B                      C
A.1           B.1                    0.2
A.1           B.2                    0.04
...           ...                    ...
A.1           B.25                   0.02
A.2           B.1                    0.04
A.2           B.2                    0.21
...           ...                    ...
A.2           B.25                   0.12
...           ...                    ...
A.1000        B.25                   0.15
```

I want to group by A and form a list of column B and C. C denotes the probability. Column B contains at most 25 unique values for each value of A. But, Some of them have probability 0.0 and are not present in the dataframe.

**The problem** Some of the values in B are missing. What I want is for each missing value in B `B.i`, I want to add the corresponding value `B.i` and `0.0` in column C. Then, I want to group by A and form a list out of B and C such that order of list is always the same for each row and sorted according to B.

**Expected Output**

```
A               B                                   C
A.1             [B.1 B.2 ... B.25]               [0.2 0.04 ... 0.02]
...
```

I did:

```
df.sort_values('B').groupby('A').agg(list)
```

But, how do I add missing values for B in each group and initialize them with 0.0 in C?

Comment: for `A.2`, you have twice `B.2`, is it a typo or you can have duplicates B value in a same A value?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I can't have duplicates in B for same A value.